# Lennon's Imagine lyric change from "living" to "sharing"? Alternative version?

Tags: lyrics

Anyone over 50 knows that in John Lennon's song "Imagine" there is a verse in the first stanza that goes "Imagine all the people living for today".

However, I just saw [a YouTube video that appeared to be a Lennon recording with overlaid lyrics that said "Imagine all the people sharing for today."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6svOHFSAH8&ab_channel=JuanPabloDellaCueva) and Lennon clearly sings the word "sharing" in the recording as well, not "living." Is this some kind of alternative version of the song that Lennon recorded, or is this some kind of digital doctoring to change the meaning of the song?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On “Imagine, The Ultimate Collection” there are several versions of the song. One alternate take (Take 1) is very similar to the one on the link you provided and listening to it and according to the lyrics in Apple Music he sings “cheering” for today, which sounds a lot like “sharing”. I believe this was a lyric that was eventually revised to what is on the original release, “living”.

Comment: Interesting one!

Comment: @Tim it’s a different arrangement than the original release, the strings pretty much play from the top, here’s a keyboard added and the drums play a bass/hat pattern during the first part of the verses.